# How to invoke AWS CLI command from CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I want to copy artifacts from S3 bucket in Account 1 to S3 bucket in Account 2. Though I was able to setup replication but I want to know whether there is a way to invoke AWS CLI command from within a pipeline.

Can it be invoked using Lambda function? If yes, any small sample script will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a Lambda Invoke action to your pipeline to call the copyobject API. The core part of the Lambda function is as follow.

```js
exports.copyRepoToProdS3 = (event, context) => {
  const jobId = event['CodePipeline.job'].id
  const s3Location = event['CodePipeline.job'].data.inputArtifacts[0].location.s3Location
  const cpParams = JSON.parse(event['CodePipeline.job'].data.actionConfiguration.configuration.UserParameters)

  let promises = []
  for (let bucket of prodBuckets) {
    let params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      CopySource: s3Location['bucketName'] + '/' + s3Location['objectKey'],
      Key: cpParams['S3ObjectKey']
    }

    promises.push(s3.copyObject(params).promise())
  }

  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Successfully copied repo to buckets!')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Failed to copy repo to buckets!', error)
    })
}
```

And more detailed steps to add roles and report processing result to CodePipeline can be find at the following link. https://medium.com/@codershunshun/how-to-invoke-aws-lambda-in-codepipeline-d7c77457af95

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer